"Something Went Wrong Error": Ionic -Capacitor Android app Google Auth Signing Issue
I integrated Google Oauth Sign In in my Angular/Ionic Capacitor App but I have an issue in Android Device:
When the user clicks on the Google login button from the app, a popup appears to select the gmail account. Suddenly afterwards the system goes into error and in the log I got this error:
Error Screenshot
I went through several posts and tried different solutions but I didn’t get a result yet.
Any Idea??
